# Class variable values get lost

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, class

I've got a image class where I want to store some information according to an image:

```
@interface GEOImage : UIImage
{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *imgDescription;
    NSString *latitude;
    NSString *longitude;
    NSDictionary *info;
    NSURL *urlToImage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title, *imgDescription, *latitude, *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *info;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *urlToImage;
@end
```

In a first tab of `TabBarController` I set for example:

```
self.chosenImage.title = @"Roflmao"
```

and in another second tab I print it out:

```
NSLog("Title:%@", self.chosenImage.title);
```

But in the second tab the title is `"null"`.
If I check the object references of `chosenImage`, they are the same, and if I print the title in the first tab after setting it, everything is ok. Somehow the class variables gets lost (or moved to trash by ARC?) when I change the tab.

Am I doing something wrong with the properties in the declaration? Or do I have some other mistake in setting class variables?

Comment: Nitpick: Your title, imgDescription, latitude, etc. are 'Instance variables' - categorically different from 'Class Variables'. Second, how are you checking that chosenImage is the same in both cases?

Comment: If this is in two separate tabs, presumably it is in two separate view controllers - wouldn't they each have their own self.chosenImage? Have you logged that too, is self.chosenImage nil?

Comment: If you're using ARC (as mentioned in your question), you should declare the properties as 'strong', not 'retain'.

Comment: @hooleyhoop: Both GEOImages have the same storage reference, so i thought they were the same. Can u tell me how i could manage the different TabBar-Tabs use the same instance of GEOImage?

Comment: @tarmes: i changed it, but i think due to the instance-problem this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Try NSLog("Self>%p Image>%p Title:%@", self, self.chosenImage, self.chosenImage.title);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the method to set the chosenImage.title was called every time the view did load, so in Tab2 the title simply was overwritten with "null". The object references were always correct.

Tanks for your help!